# Why does tableau throw a cursor error after adding column store index?

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

I added a clustered column store index to one of my DW tables and as soon as i did that tableau throws this error when i try to join to it.

[image]

has anyone run into this before?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192479/what-to-do-when-you-need-a-cursor-and-you-have-a-columnstore-clustered-index

Comment: https://www.easysoft.com/blog/cursors-clustered-columnstore-index.html

Answer (score 1):

On SQL 2016 and later, as a workaround you can create a nonclustered Columnstore index on the table instead.  The table will retain its clustered index (or heap), and the additional Columnstore will be used by queries that can take advantage of it.

eg:

```
drop table if exists cs_test 
create table cs_test (a int primary key, b int)

create nonclustered columnstore index ncci_test on cs_test(a,b)

go

declare c cursor local for select * from cs_test
```